# Best way to handle responsiveness in Next.JS

Tags: next.js, responsive

Currently in my websites for Next.JS, I retrieve the page dimensions via a UseDimensions function like so:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function UseDimensions() {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = React.useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setWindowSize({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    });
    function handleResize() {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        setWindowSize({
          width: window.innerWidth,
          height: window.innerHeight,
        });
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    handleResize();

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return windowSize;
}
```

And then I can conditionally render (per example container padding) as done here:

```
import * as React from "react";

import UseDimensions from "../../services/UseDimensions";
import Breakpoints from "../../styles/Breakpoints";

export default function Container(props) {
  const size = UseDimensions();

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "center",
          backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
          width: "100%",
          ...props.style,
        }}
        id={props.id}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            padding:
              props.padding ??
              (size.width < Breakpoints.sm
                ? `${props.paddingVert ?? "4rem"} 2rem`
                : size.width < Breakpoints.md
                ? `${props.paddingVert ?? "4rem"} 4rem`
                : `${props.paddingVert ?? "4rem"} 8rem`),
            width: "100%",
            maxWidth: 2000,
            ...props.innerStyle,
          }}
        >
          {props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The problem however, is that Google Lighthouse doesn't like my mobile versions very much. It is complaining about cumilative layout shift due to this method of rendering. Does anyone know a better alternative to responsively render Next.JS websites?

Comment: CSS is the best place for setting up responsive layouts, not JavaScript. The fact that you're using NextJS to produce your markup doesn't change that.

Comment: You should really just learn how to create responsive layouts with CSS, even [React recommended this over inline styles](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style). It's a pretty nuanced subject so you should probably just look up a tutorial.

Comment: Alright, so just refrain from using responsiveness in JS, got it! Thanks everyone!